# Direct image for crystals?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If we get a morphism $f : X \to Y$ of schemes over $k$, how should I define the direct image functor
$$
f_* : Crys(X) \to Crys(Y)?
$$
By a crystal I mean a quasi-coherent sheaf $M$ on $X$ with a collection of isomorphisms (a stratification) between the pullbacks $x^*M \simeq y^*M$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are morphisms from $Spec(R)$ for a commuting ring $R$ which give the same morphisms from $Spec(R/Nil(R))$. Also there are other conditions when $f : Spec(R) \to Spec(S)$ but I omit these.

So my question is how to define the supposed direct image functor, and any help with this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is quasi-finite, you can follow chapter IV of Berthelot's thesis (Springer Lecture notes 407).  Otherwise, you will need to enter the derived world, much like in the case of D-modules.  [Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/crystext.pdf) defines a crystalline pushforward by taking a derived pushforward of ind-coherent sheaves along the corresponding morphism of de Rham stacks.